# JQuery JCarousel (not lite) and mousewheel. need help

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel, mousewheel

I use those js files below:

```
jquery-1.4.2.min.js
include/jcarousel/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js
include/mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js
```

in my index.php file i got :

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#mycarousel').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
                    if (delta > 0)
                    {carousel.prev();}
                    else if (delta < 0)
                    {carousel.next();}
        });
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({

    size: mycarousel_itemList.length,
    itemLoadCallback: {onBeforeAnimation: mycarousel_itemLoadCallback},
visible: 3,
btnNext: null,
 btnPrev: null,

});

});
```

I believe the problem is with

```
{carousel.prev();}
{carousel.next();}
```

I want to add mousewheel to my jcarousel but i cant find the appropriate function to be called when i scroll my wheel. 
Please help me. Further information maybe requested. I'm doing on my own till now. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

carousel.prev(); and carousel.next(); will not work as carousel is undefined. You need to specify a callback function in which you can then manually run the carousel functions.

For Example:

```
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({    
    size: mycarousel_itemList.length,
    itemLoadCallback: {onBeforeAnimation: mycarousel_itemLoadCallback},
    visible: 3,
    btnNext: null,
    btnPrev: null,
    // The callback function to run
    initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,    
});

function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {
    // All code referencing the carousel in here.
    jQuery('#mycarousel').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
        if (delta > 0)
            {carousel.prev();}
        else if (delta < 0)
            {carousel.next();}
        });

}
```

Read more here in this example: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_controls.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Insert my code snippet in your **jquery.jcarousel.js**
after this line:

$(window).bind('load.jcarousel', function() { windowLoaded = true; });

```
// Activate the mouse wheel function --------------------------
$('.jcarousel').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
    if (delta > 0)
        self.prev();
    else if (delta < 0)
        self.next();
});
```